# Installing forge package in Octave

Tags: installation, octave

I am trying to `install forge odepkg` in `Octave 4.0.0` on `Windows`. However, when I try with

```
pkg install -forge  odepkg-0.8.5
```

I get this error:

> cellfun: C must be a cell array

Anyone can help?

Comment: There is no package named `odepkg-0.8.5`. There is a package named `odepkg` though, so use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download new version of Octave (4.0.1) for Windows ([octave-4.0.1-installer.exe](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/octave-4.0.1-installer.exe)). The **odepkg** package and a lot of another packages are installed already in this distributive. So for using **odepkg**  you need type only one command:

```
pkg load odepkg
```